# NSInteger value not valid when passing in a variable, for custom table view class delegate method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsinteger

I'm testing a custom table view style class:

[HorizontalTable](https://github.com/TheVole/HorizontalTable)

It produces a horizontal table view.

One of the delegate methods equivalent to `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfColumnsForTableView:(HorizontalTableView *)tableView.
```

If I give this a number (ex: `return 10;`) it is happy and it give me the number "cells" that I want. But if I feed it a value of `someArray.count` or an `int` or `NSInteger` variable, the table view just comes out blank, delivering no cells.

I think that the method in the custom table view class that receives the `NSInteger` value is this:

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfPages {
    NSInteger numPages = 0;
    if (_delegate)
        numPages = [_delegate numberOfColumnsForTableView:self];
    return numPages;
}
```

Do I need to cast the result of `someArray.count` to an `NSInteger`?

Comment: What are you returning in your `numberOfColumnsForTableView:`? maybe the array is nil or the array.count is returning 0?

Comment: did you print the numPages means NSLog(@"Total record %d",numPages);

Comment: someArray.count will return an int value. There is no need for conversion. You can use NSInteger any place you use an int without converting it. Check if your array is nil or if someArray.count do in fact return 0...

Comment: Thanks. I don't think it is nil.  The code I am using is: return _cellsArray.count. The cellsArray is defined in viewDidLoad as follows and returns 6 with the following log.  _cellsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"item 1", @"item 2",@"item 3", @"item 4",@"item 5", @"item 6", nil];
    NSLog(@"num %d", _cellsArray.count);

Comment: @ParasJoshi using your log in the - (NSUInteger)numberOfPages method, the total record is 0 when I return  _cellsArray.count;, and 6 when I return 6; in the numberOfColumnsForTableView: method.

Comment: can you please show your array code???

Comment: @Rajneesh071 _cellsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"item 1", @"item 2",@"item 3", @"item 4",@"item 5", @"item 6", nil]; But see my answer for more details.

Comment: yup thats why i was asking you the code of your array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact converting the value to be returned to the count of an NSArray, as opposed to the count an NSMutableArray fixes the issue. Why? I am not sure why an NSArray's count value is valid but not the NSMutableArray's. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Here you get the value from array means your array not nil so just debug and check the if condition that its come in that condition or not and what you get from `NSLog`

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfPages {
    NSInteger numPages = 0;
    if (_delegate){
        numPages = [_delegate numberOfColumnsForTableView:self];
        NSLog(@"Total record %d",numPages);//what you get here?
    }
    return numPages;
}
```

Comment: using your log in the - (NSUInteger)numberOfPages method, the total record is 0 when I return _cellsArray.count;, and 6 when I return 6; in the numberOfColumnsForTableView: method.

Comment: 2012-12-26 20:18:59.412 HorizontalTableViewScroller[1848:907] Total record 0

Comment: Thats the point dude... here you get 0 so you get blank screen dude... create proper array and return like [yourArray count];

Comment: Thanks, but I thought I was creating a proper array that does have a count of 6 as returned by the NSLog I described above. If you have a minute please check out the project. owolf.net/uploads/StackOverflow/HorizontalTableViewScroller.zip

Comment: Thanks for your time man, sorry to trouble you but that is the proper url : owolf.net/uploads/StackOverflow/HorizontalTableViewScroller.zip

Comment: confused dude.. bcoz i think here class not get the view referance then whats the option so i will post something which i got it...ok dude... :)

Comment: @Mrwolfy : I checked the project. I can see only two possibilities:Either When u are taking the count from the array like arr.count, the array is nil, or the array count is 0. You can check that by printing array count before passing as parameter.

Comment: well I fixed it, by looking at the original source code. It likes the count value of an NSArray, but will not accept the value of an NSMutableArray's count, so converting to an NSArray fixes the problem, not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

```
numPages = [_delegate numberOfColumnsForTableView:self];
//self requires an object of type  HorizontalTableView
```

Comment: Thanks! That sounds like something, but I don't quite get it. Does that mean that I need to change me input in the numberOfColumnsForTableView: method? to what?

Comment: Yes. you need to pass an object of type HorizontalTableView.

Comment: - (NSInteger)numberOfColumnsForTableView:(HorizontalTableView *)tableView    . You are passing 'self' . Is that correct object type?

Comment: I feel a bit dense here: so I return what in that method?

Comment: I think to answer your question, the answer is yes. That is the class where that method exists.

Comment: feel free to check out the project if you have a minute: owolf.net/uploads/StackOverflow/HorizontalTableViewScroller.zip

Answer (score 1):

[NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is editable, where as [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) is read-only.

`NSMutableArray` is a subclass of `NSArray` and responds to messages such as `addObject`, `removeObject` and so forth; i.e. it is mutable, like the name says. Instead, `NSArray` is immutable, i.e. you can't add/remove objects.

Comment: Does this answer why the NSMutableArray.count is invalid as input while the NSArray.count works in the methods described?

Comment: have you tried this...or if not working then send me code of both NSMutableArray and NSArray

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Yes, I just rewarded myself for the answer below. But I'd rather give it to you if you can clearly explain why this worked.

Comment: actually i am unable to understand you..can you please more specific?

Comment: read my answer if you can explain why: an NSArray's count value is valid but not the NSMutableArray's as the solution to my original question. In other words, I changed my NSMutableArray to an NSArray and it worked.

Comment: NSMutableArray *myMutArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"item1",@"item2",@"item3", nil];
    NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:myMutArray];

Comment: NSLog(@"%d",myMutArray.count); its printing value 3 at my end

Comment: Thanks, but maybe you don't understand my question, or it is not a valid question, as I am in the learning stages.

Comment: if you look at my original question, you will see that the method that receives the input is: "- (NSUInteger)numberOfPages". So the question is: why is the result of myNSArray.count valid and good for this input, but the result of myNSMutableArray.count not good, (that is it returns a blank table). I am adding the same "objects" data to both arrays, both will log as the same value. What is the difference between these results and why does it matter?